# jQuery vertical menu problems

Tags: jquery, css, submenu

I created a vertical menu that opens and closes with a click function. The client wanted this and I do not really have control over the design of the menu. That being said I have a few questions that I would like some help with. First off when the submenu is opened and you are not hovering over the menu then the submenu is not shown anymore. Also, when you open the submenu with the ul it only allows to be closed if you click the same link again. Any help would be wonderful. Thank you!

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var submenu = $('#cssmenu ul .has-sub');
    var hidden = true; 
    submenu.click(function() {
    if (hidden) {
    $(this).animate({width: '280px'});
    } else {
    $(this).animate({width: '140px'});
    }
    hidden = !hidden;
    });
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/enks2ky0/

Comment: I think you are going about this the wrong way. There is nothing here that screams: "I NEED JAVASCRIPT TO WORK!". Consider using :hover selectors and make the subnav `<ul>`s children of the parent menu list items. You can easily create the same behavior by using relative and absolute positioning, and you can animate it by using `transition-duration`. I'll go into more detail in an answer if you are open to a pure CSS menu

Comment: I am open to use strictly css but the client wants the menu to be clickable not a hover effect. I actually would much rather just use css but is there a way to do that without javascript?

Comment: Consider [**something like this**](https://jsfiddle.net/enks2ky0/1/). Since you do need the menu to stay open onclick, you will need to use some javascript, but it is minimal. The majority of the transitions, hiding, and showing can, and should, be done in the CSS.

Comment: Thank you I like that option and I appreciate your help!

Comment: There is still a problem where its not showing more than one sub-menu link. The first two have multiple links. The only way I can get them to show is disable visibility for ul .has-sub*

Comment: You appear to have a pretty strange layout on your menu. You may need to restructure it. I don't know why you have your li.last outside of your subnav ul. Typically it works like this: ul (main) -> li (main item) -> ul (sub) -> li (sub item). This works best because then the entire subnav ul is a child of the main item li, so it counts as a hover on the main item li when you are hovering over the ul. Furthermore, instead of using li.first and li.last, consider li:first-child and li:last-child. That will prevent you from having to use classes and will perform the same effect.